# Plot3D: Drawing Points at Mesh Intersections

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to draw points at the visible Mesh intersections, like this:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {1, 4}, Boxed -> False]
```

Desired output:

[image]

I could calculate where the Mesh is going to be, based on PlotRange and the Mesh cardinality, and draw points there, but I think there should be an easier alternative way.

A big plus is to be able to chose the point color based upon the function value. Also, labeling the points would be wonderful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, I like the simple solution as well. Plus it is easy to use the same coloring function for both the surface and the points:

```
g = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {1, 4}, Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
p = ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y^2]}, {x, -3, 3, (3 - (-3))/(1 + 1)}, {y, -2, 2, (2 - (-2))/(4 + 1)}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]];
Show[g, p]
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If we want to make this into a customized myPlot3D, I think the following should do:

```
myPlot3D[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
   Mesh -> {i_Integer, j_Integer}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{g = 
     Plot3D[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, Mesh -> {i, j}, 
      Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot3D]]],
    stx = (xmax - xmin)/(i + 1),
    sty = (ymax - ymin)/(j + 1), pts},
   pts = ListPointPlot3D[
     Table[{x, y, f}, {x, xmin + stx, xmax - stx, stx}, {y, 
       ymin + sty, ymax - sty, sty}], 
     Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPointPlot3D]]];
   Show[g, pts]];
```

Note that options are applied to both plots, but are filtered first. I also removed the points on the contour of the plot. For example,

```
myPlot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {4, 10}, 
 Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

will give as a result

[image]

Comment: @Felix Trying to generalize this in my answer. Do you see a better way?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very hackish approach: Grab the mesh lines in the output and look for intersections. It is quite doable since the output is a `GraphicsComplex`.
First, find the indices of the mesh line points in the graphics complex:

```
g=Plot3D[Sin[x+y^2],{x,-3,3},{y,-2,2},Mesh->{1,4},Boxed->False];
meshlineptindices=First/@Cases[g, _Line, Infinity]
```

Now, go through the lines pairwise and look for intersections. The following, uses `NestWhile` to recursively look at all pairs (first line, another line) for shorter and shorter sublists of the original list of meshlines. The resulting intersections are returned via `Sow`:

```
intesectionindices=
  Flatten@Reap@NestWhile[(
    Sow@Outer[Intersection,{First[#]},Rest[#],1]; 
    Rest[#]
  )&, meshlineptindices, Length[#]>0&]

Out[4]= {1260,1491,1264,1401,1284,1371,1298,1448,1205,1219,1528,1525,1526,1527}
```

Look up the indices in the `GraphicsComplex`:

```
intesections = Part[g[[1,1]],intesectionindices]
Out[5]= {{-3.,-1.2,-0.997667},{3.,-1.2,-0.961188},<...>,{0.,1.2,0.977754}}
```

Finally, show the points together with original graphics:

```
Show[g,Graphics3D[{Red,PointSize[Large],Point[intesections]}]]
```

[image: output graphics]

HTH

**Update**: To get the colored points, you could just use

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large],({colorfunction[Last@#],Point[#]}&)/@intesections]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, Janus beat me to writing the answer. I couldn't figure out the part of using Part.
In any case, here is a simplified version:

```
g = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {1, 4}, Boxed -> False];
index = Cases[Cases[g, _Line, \[Infinity]], _Integer, \[Infinity]];
inter = Part[Select[Tally@index, Part[#, 2] > 1 &], All, 1];
Show[g, Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Part[g[[1, 1]], inter]]}]]
```

[image: Image Output]

**Update:**

If you only want the intersections of the mesh then you need to remove the points that are on the boundary. Here I make a 4 by 4 mesh.

```
g = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {4, 4}, Boxed -> False];
index = Cases[Cases[g, _Line, \[Infinity]], _Integer, \[Infinity]];
inter = Part[Select[Tally@index, Part[#, 2] > 1 &], All, 1];
range = AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange][[1]][[2]];
interior = Select[
   Part[g[[1, 1]], inter],
   IntervalMemberQ[Interval[range[[1]]]*0.9999,  Part[#, 1]]  
     && 
     IntervalMemberQ[Interval[range[[2]]]*0.9999,  Part[#, 2]] 
    &
   ];
Show[g, Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[interior] }]]
```

[image: Interior Points]

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, I prefer to stay away from messing up with the Graphics FullForm. So, going into my original lines, almost the same as FelixCQ did and trying to get a general function.

```
Options[myPlot3D] = Options[Plot3D];
myPlot3D[f_, p__] :=
  Module[
   {g = Plot3D[f, p],
    (*Get the Mesh Divisions*)
    m = Flatten@Cases[{p}, HoldPattern[Rule[Mesh, r_]] -> r],
    stx, sty},
   (*Get PlotRange*)
   pr = (List @@@ Options[g, PlotRange])[[1, 2]];
   (*Get Mesh steps*)
   stx = (pr[[1, 2]] - pr[[1, 1]])/(First@m + 1);
   sty = (pr[[2, 2]] - pr[[2, 1]])/(Last@m + 1);
   (*Generate points*)
   pts = Point[
     Flatten[Table[{a, b, f /. {x -> a, y -> b}}, {a, 
        pr[[1, 1]] + stx, pr[[1, 2]] - stx, stx},
       {b, pr[[2, 1]] + sty, pr[[2, 2]] - sty, sty}], 1]];
   Show[g, Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], pts}]]
   ];

myPlot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {1, 2}, 
 Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Axes -> False]
```

[image]

The main problem here is that the plotted function must depend on formal parameters `x` and `y` ... must solve it :(

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this is what you are looking for!